# Unicode character (U+F8F1) not set up for use with LaTeX. \end{align*}

Tags: errors, align, unicode

A `LaTeX` PDF doesn't have any errors before formatting. After formatting and setting in LaTeX, I get this error :

> Unicode character  (U+F8F1) not set up for use with LaTeX. \end{align*}

I don't use any special characters, such as Greek characters. What is wrong?

```
\begin{align*}
    &f+g
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Please show a full example. There is nothing obvious wrong with your code snippet, but that's not the whole story. U+F8F1 is from Unicode's Private Use Area, by the way.

Comment: you will have added the character U+F8F1 (which is  private use character not defined by Unicode) delete that line and re-type.  The character is not in the code you posted here. Please always post complete small documents and check they produce the message you are asking about.